# spring MVC XmlViewResolver configuration

Tags: spring-mvc

We're wanting to provide alternative PDF views as well as regular JSP views  from our controllers and have added a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` and an `XmlViewResolver` to handle this.
All the examples I've found, including the Spring docs, return a simple view name, which the `XmlViewResolver` maps to a bean ID in its views.xml file ( in our case, a bean that writes PDF to the `HttpResponse`).

However we have our jsps organised in subfolders of the location defined in our InternalResourceViewResolver.

E.g.,

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"  p:order="2">          
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
```

So, from within our controller we return view names like "a/b/c" for a JSP that is in /WEB-INF/pages/a/b/c.jsp.

This works fine for JSPs, except that you can't have a bean id defined in views.xml as 'a/b/c'; it's not a valid bean ID. 
We've investigated several options that either don't work are not satisfactory:

1. Put all JSPs in a single folder so that we can just use a bean-id-naming-compatible  view name that can be resolved by an `XmlViewResolver`. This works but isn't ideal for organising our JSPs.
2. Have multiple `InternalResourceViewResolver` definitions using different prefixes. This just doesn't work; the first resolver of this type does not return null if it fails to find a matching view, it just fails with an exception and subsequent `ViewResolvers` are not used.
3. Use a separate controller method (or conditional code in the controller that returns the view name depending on what is the requested content type or URL suffix); these solutions seem to defeat the purpose of keeping a `Controller` ignorant of its views.
4. Try using wild-cards in the `location` property of XmlViewResolver; this fails with an exception.

I'm sure there is a nice elegant solution but it is eluding me just now. Is there a better approach such that I can return a view name like 'a/b/c' which has the potential to be resolved by an XmlViewResolver ?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, bean aliases are the way to go...after a bit of digging around:

In the views.xml file targetted by XmlViewResolver:

```
<bean id="PdfView" class="com.blah.PdfDocView" /> 
<alias name="PdfView" alias="/a/b/structuredDocument"/>
```

which maps '/a/b/structuredDocument' to the PdfDocView bean.